# FaceBook Share on Android

Tags: android

I am unable to get share my screen on facebook wall below is my code.
Can you please help me how to take screen shot of my activity and post on facebook wall

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // share button
    private ShareButton shareButton;
    // image
    private Bitmap image;
    // counter
    private int counter = 0;
    //private ShareContent shareContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // initialize facebook sdk
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // share button
        shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {


                    postPicture();
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void postPicture() {
        // check counter
        if (counter == 1) {
            // save the screenshot
            View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
            rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            // creates immutable clone of image
            image = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
            // destroy
            rootView.destroyDrawingCache();

            // share dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder shareDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            shareDialog.setTitle("Share Screen Shot");
            shareDialog.setMessage("Share image to Facebook?");
            shareDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // share the image to Facebook
                            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                    .setBitmap(image).build();
                            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                    .addPhoto(photo).build();
                            shareButton.setShareContent(content);
                            counter = 1;
                            shareButton.performClick();
                        }
                    });
            shareDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            shareDialog.show();
        } else {
            counter = 0;
            shareButton.setShareContent(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error? Please post stacktrace if any

Comment: does facebook native app is installed in your device

Comment: yes installed But No error is showing when i pressed on fshare Button it just toast the message "Share image to Facebook?" i pressed yes but nothing happend.

Comment: My main Aim is when i press FShare Button on my app the Entire screen will be posted on the FaceBook Wall

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android Like this